# ElasticSearch : How to combine nested 'AND' Not Equal

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I want build query for search matching with nested and not equal.

This is my elasticSearch query:

```
{
    "from":0,"size":1000,
    "query":{
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "data",
            "query" : {
                "match" : {
                    "data.city" : "california"
                }
            }
        },
        "filter":{
            "not":{
                "filter":{
                    "term":{
                        "_id":"01921asda01201"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I got error, am I write something wrong ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bool Filter` too with `must` and `must_not` clause.

```
{
"from": 0,
"size": 1000,
"filter": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "nested": {
              "path": "data",
              "query": {
                 "match": {
                    "data.city": "california"
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     ],
     "must_not": [
        {
           "term": {
              "_id": "01921asda01201"
           }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure about the top-level `filter` section, @Richa?

Comment: @ Val :: you mean `bool filter`

Comment: At the top level, you have `from`, `size` and `filter`, it should be `from`, `size` and `query`

Comment: If I am not wrong, we can directly use filters without using query.

Comment: Yes, but that was [deprecated in 0.90.8](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/search-request-post-filter.html) and [renamed to `post_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/_search_requests.html). And if the OP was to add aggregations to his query, then it would probably not work as expected.

Comment: Since it was deprecated in 0.90.8, I'm not sure why it's still available in 2.x...  there must be a reason :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [filtered query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html)

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path" : "data",
            "query" : {
                "match" : {
                    "data.city" : "california"
                }
            }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "_id": "01921asda01201"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that it is a good practice to use POST when sending a payload. Under the hood Sense uses POST instead of GET when sending a payload.

Comment: also - the `filtered` query is deprecated as of Elasticsearch 2.0.0

Comment: Yes.. and the alternative is also specified on the same link i.e. to use bool query in that case

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) for this, and put your two clauses in the `must` and `must_not` sections respectively.

If you don't care about scoring on the `data.city` field (from your example it's not clear), you might want to use the `filter` portion instead of the `must` portion.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "data",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "data.city": "california"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": "01921asda01201"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```